# Automating Daily signoff sheet

Tags: digital-signature

I have a process where I need to get a signature from staff on a checklist to acknowledge the fact that thet have completed their work on that specific job. This is as per audit requireent. There are around 500 jobs which are typically distributed to various staff and they are bound to signoff the same on a daily basis post completeting the work on that specific job.

Is there a way the signature part can be automated on sharepoint. I do not mean to have a physical signature done, instead if the sharepoint can restrict the job access to the specified staff and then the privilege to be assigned to staff based on their login credentials into the system.

If anyone can help, please let me know how this can be done in sharepoint.

Ramakath

Comment: This question most likely belongs on [sharepoint.se] instead of here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about the workplace as defined in the [help/on-topic]. I suggest you take a look at [sharepoint.se] to see if you could ask a similar question there. Be sure to read their help center to make sure your question is on topic there first!